# unexpected value for an element in string being printed

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm doing an encode-decode question. As you can see below, I've made a condition that if the ith element of message and decode aren't alpha, they should be printed as they are. But for some reason, instead of a special character, I'm getting weird answers.

```
def encode(message, key):
    encryption = ""
    for i in range (len(message)):
        if message[i].isalpha == False:
            encryption += message[i]
        else:
            if message[i].upper == True:
                if ord(message[i]) + key <= 90:
                    encryption += chr(ord(message[i]) + key)
                else:
                    encryption += chr(ord((message[i])) + key - 91 + 65)
            else:
                if ord(message[i]) + key <= 122:
                    encryption += chr(ord(message[i]) + key)
                else:
                    encryption += chr(ord(message[i]) + key - 123 + 97)
            encryption = encryption.upper()
    return encryption
def decode(code, key):
    decryption = ""
    for i in range(len(code)):
        print (code[i])
        if code[i].isalpha == False:
            decryption += code[i]
        else:
            if ord(code[i]) - key >= 65:
                decryption += chr(ord(code[i]) - key)
            else:
                    decryption += chr(ord(code[i]) - key - 65 + 91)
    return decryption
print(encode(input().strip(), int(input().strip()))
      if input().strip() == '1'
      else decode(input().strip(), int(input().strip())))
```

```
input:
     2 (1 means encode 2 means decode)
     LOSXQ PYVVYGON MKXMOV WOODSXQ
     10 (number of letters back)
output:
     BEING0FOLLOWED0CANCEL0MEETING
actual answer:
     BEING FOLLOWED CANCEL MEETING

input:
     1
     Et tu, Brute--Then fall, Caesar!
     2
output:
     GV"VW."DTWVG//VJGP"HCNN."ECGUCT#
actual answer:
     GV VW, DTWVG--VJGP HCNN, ECGUCT!
```

I'm getting issues at special characters and I don't understand why even though I have explicitly conditioned it in the code.
`

Comment: `.isalpha` is a function, you need `()` after it to call it. `if not message[i].isalpha():`

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: omg this actually solved it @Barmar !!! Really appreciate your help with this I was struggling since quite a while ;-; can you actually tell me what was my isalpha without the brackets printing?

Comment: It's just testing the function object itself. Which is always truthy.

Comment: Try doing `print("abc".isalpha)`

Comment: @Barmar it says <built-in method isalpha of str object at memory address> (the memory address is the 0xc values but for some reason I couldn't copy the output from vscode so I just wrote it like this)

Comment: That's right. That's the method function itself, rather than the result of calling it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def encode(message, key):
    encryption = ""
    for i in range(len(message)):
        if not message[i].isalpha():
            encryption += message[i]
        else:
            if message[i].isupper():
                if ord(message[i]) + key <= 90:
                    encryption += chr(ord(message[i]) + key)
                else:
                    encryption += chr(ord(message[i]) + key - 91 + 65)
            else:
                if ord(message[i]) + key <= 122:
                    encryption += chr(ord(message[i]) + key)
                else:
                    encryption += chr(ord(message[i]) + key - 123 + 97)
    return encryption.upper()

def decode(code, key):
    decryption = ""
    for i in range(len(code)):
        if not code[i].isalpha():
            decryption += code[i]
        else:
            if ord(code[i]) - key >= 65:
                decryption += chr(ord(code[i]) - key)
            else:
                decryption += chr(ord(code[i]) - key - 65 + 91)
    return decryption

choice = int(input().strip())
message = input().strip()
key = int(input().strip())

if choice == 1:
    print(encode(message, key))
elif choice == 2:
    print(decode(message, key))
```

It looks like there are a couple of issues in your code. The first issue is that you are not calling the `isalpha` and `upper` methods correctly. The correct usage is `message[i].isalpha()` and `message[i].upper()`. The second issue is with the indentation of `encryption = encryption.upper()`. It should be outside the loop to convert the entire string to uppercase, not inside the loop.

Comment: That just made me cry on this question for 4 hours lol. Because I was returning the values, it printed the boolean state of the isupper and islower if I did it outside loop.

Comment: is it because I gave you the wrong answer or just that you realised your mistake? also did you solve your issue?

Comment: I realized my mistake lol. Yeah I was able to solve the issue (even though I don't remember how it's an old thing now xd)